# How do I solve the connection error when I debug?

Tags: c#, sql-server, debugging, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2019

I have 2 projects in 1 solution. When I try to run my VitekAPI project I get an error: "Unable to connect to web server 'IIS Express'"

[image: Error]

In my startup class inside my ConfigureServices method I have the following service added:

```
            services.AddDbContext<BusinessContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

in my appsettings.json file inside my VitekAPI Project I have added the following as my DefaultConnection:

```
 "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=BusinessContext-bc;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

My database is up as well:
[image: Database]

The following is a link to my repository:
https://github.com/tux-superman/MVCandAPI

Comment: try to close and reopen VS

Comment: Thankyou. That worked but I have no idea why.

Comment: It is about to connect to IIS Express and Dependent service, not DB connection and mostly for windows permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Try to close and reopen VS`....